# Need to create shopify FAQ application. what is the best way of store FAQs on Shopify's database

Tags: shopify

I am creating shopify FAQ app. There is full CRUD operation in this application. I dont need to maintain my own database I need to use Shopping's database so how can i do that. what are the endpoints should I use?

I need to know are there specific endpoints,

Answer (score 0):

A Shop has Metafields and MetaObjects. Simply attach your FAQ as resources to the Shop. Since your FAQ is likely just text, you can do this using String types. If you want your strings translatable, you'll have to investigate how to handle that as a theme app extension. If you choose to be a FAQ via theme app extension, it is possible translations would be stored in the theme schema you create.

So those are your two easy-peasy choices. Shop Metafields or Theme App Extension.